# Joomla newbie can't get article title to show on category view

Tags: joomla

I just setup Joomla 1.5 on a Windows 2003 Server via WAMP.

I can't understand why article titles are not showing in the category view. There is one article in the view, but it does not show the title.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks, Lars

Comment: Solved:

content-->article manager-->Parameters (top right)-->'show article title' is set to yes

Answer (score 2):

content-->article manager-->Parameters (top right)--> 'show article title' is set to yes

Answer (score 0):

Your articles should be mapped to section and to category in order to be displayed properly on front-end.

Comment: Each article is mapped to a section/category. In the first case it's Lighting/Fluorescent Lighting and the second it's Lighting/Recessed Lighting.

Each article shows as published in the Article Manager, not on the front page, and shows the section and category for each.